# How to use Stream callbacks in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a few questions (I am new to Dart) w.r.t the code below which I found. What I am trying to achieve:
1) Write more than one line in the brackets for errors. But I get error saying 'set literals were supported upto 2.2....'. It would also be good to know the list of possible errors so I can alert the user accordingly.

2) Increment a counter pertaining to number of documents and keep storing document id's in one variable, by overwriting the last value if more than one document is found. I am trying to check that there should only be one document and take action if counter goes to 2.

```
void _checkIfAdmin() {
Firestore.instance
    .collection('Admin')
    .where('Email', isEqualTo: widget._user.email)
    .snapshots()
    .handleError((error)=>{
      //
      })
    .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => gpCounter+=1)); // Store document id?
print('Counter: $gpCounter');
```

}

Here I am getting printed gpCounter=0 when I know there are two documents in there. I tried adding async/await in the function but it seems the firebase statement does not return any future so I get a warning to use await only for futures.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to address as many issues as I could understand in your question. If you have any other issues, you should probably ask another question.

1. **Set literals**: the syntax for anonymous functions is `() {}` and not `() => {}`.
   `() =>` is a shorthand syntax to return the value of a single expressions and in your case, you are returning a `Set` in your anonymous functions because `{}` create `Set`'s (or `Map`'s if you have colons in there).
   The solution for this is `(error) { ... }`.
2. You print your `gpCounter` value **synchronously**, however, you are listening to a [`Stream`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html).
   Because of that, you should move your `print` statement to your `listen` function:

```dart
    .listen(data) {
        print('Counter: ${data.documents.length}');
      })
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes it makes sense to me. But when can I use these variables? i.e. How do I know they are ready to be used somewhere else in the code?

Comment: I actually want to use the value of received 'documentID' outside of this function, not sure how to go about it. Is there a way to get this document list as one shot?

Comment: @Damandroid Yes, you can use [`getDocuments`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) and [`await` that `Future`](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures) or use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).